# Aren't 6 digits guarantee in single precision?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Here's the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c4d5e32a02f4f05):

```
typedef std::numeric_limits<float> fl;

int main()
{   
    std::cout.precision(100);    

    float f1 = 9999978e3;
    std::cout << f1 << " (9999978e3 decimal number stored as binary)" << std::endl;

    float f2 = 9999979e3;
    std::cout << f2 << " (9999979e3 decimal number stored as binary)" << std::endl;

    float f3 = 9999990e3;
    std::cout << f3 << " (9999990e3 decimal number stored as binary)" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "-----^" << std::endl;
}
```

which prints:

```
9999978496 (9999978e3 decimal number stored as binary)
9999978496 (9999979e3 decimal number stored as binary)
9999989760 (9999990e3 decimal number stored as binary)
-----^
```

The decimal numbers stored as binary correctly keep the 6th digit for `9999978e3` and `9999979e3` (which is **7**), but the 6th digit of `9999990e3` is **8** and not **9**.

Shouldn't floating point precision always guarantee the first 6 digits?

Yes, if I round **89** I got **9**, but that's not the same; this will work/make sense only "visually".

Later (on processing numbers), when I'll apply math on that value, it'll work on a `xxxxx8` number (99999**8**9760), and not on a `xxxxx9`. +1 at that magnitude.

Comment: 6 digits are definitely not guaranteed

Comment: "If a decimal string with at most 6 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 single-precision representation, and **then converted back to a decimal string with the same number of digits**, the final result should match the original string." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Its a rough estimate thats easy to remember, not a steadfast rule

Comment: The 6 digits are guaranteed when you take into account rounding. I don't understand why you say that you don't accept this in your question.

Comment: @interjay because when you apply "math" at that magnitude, there's no rounding :O

Comment: @markzzz What do you mean by "apply math"? And why do you think there's no rounding?

Comment: @markzzz When you apply "math" there are no decimal digits either, so I don't understand the significance. The number is still closer to 9999990e3 than to 9999980e3.

Comment: Nicely put question by the way. Why am I the only upvoter?

Comment: If you don't round, you can get *zero* matching digits. For example, if you convert 0.999999999 to floating point, and back, you'll get 1.0, which has zero matching digits. Rounding is mandatory here.

Comment: You can play with this IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: @interjay: if "6 digits" were guarantee, I aspect that the first 6 digits I got ARE THOSE, not coming from rounding. I always see them considered "preserved". Such as if I have `1.00005`, all of them respect the magnitude. World destroyed http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccb499739861eacb

Comment: Then you misunderstand the guarantee. The point of floating point is to be as accurate as possible given the limitations. Your version of the guarantee would be less accurate. Maybe you're using binary floating point for something which shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @interjay: I think I got the point. But I believe this works only if `round(a) + round(b) = round(a + b)`. Is that guarantee? If so I understand why I don't need "exact 6 digits" but I can rely on rounding ULP...

Comment: No, that isn't guaranteed. When you do operations like addition you lose some accuracy, so after enough operations you won't have the 6 digits accuracy even after rounding.

Comment: @interjay: that's what I'm talking about. If I have a 0.xxxxxY decimal number and another one as 0.xxxxxZ (which the 6° digits for both are get by rounding, since its not preserved by internal binary storing after the conversion to decimal again), I can't rely later on their rounding, because they are not (in fact) keeping "that" magnitude when I'll elaborate them. So if I (think to have) a number with a value at some magnitude and another with another value at the same magnitude, when I sum it, the magnitude value can be not respected.

Comment: Your version of the guarantee (based on truncation) would also not be preserved after addition, so it doesn't actually get you anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158408/discussion-between-markzzz-and-interjay).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in the way you think it's guaranteed, no.

By way of offering a counter-example, for an IEEE754 single precision floating point, the closest number to

```
9999990000
```

is

```
9999989760
```

What *is* guaranteed is that your number and the `float`, when both are rounded to six significant figures, will be the same. This is be the value of `FLT_DIG` on your platform, assuming it implements IEEE754.  E.g. the closest `float` number to `9999979000` is `9999978496`.

See http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Comment: Really? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32

Comment: "This gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision. If a decimal string with at most 6 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 single-precision representation, and then converted back to a decimal string with the same number of digits, the final result should match the original string. If an IEEE 754 single-precision number is converted to a decimal string with at least 9 significant digits, and then converted back to single-precision representation, the final result must match the original number." Wrong?

Comment: @interjay: Yes, I've made the answer a little more mature - see the penultimate paragraph.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia quote should say or should be read as ".. and then converted back to a decimal string with the same number of **significant** digits .." It implies that because otherwise it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thus "6 significant digits" **ONLY** means that **ONCE YOU ROUND** the converted `decimal-binary-decimal` value, the starting decimal is equal to the converted-back decimal. So basically it guarantees that ULP between the two decimal is around +-0.5?

Comment: Re: “… your number and the `float`, when both are rounded to seven significant figures… will be the same.” Seven is not guaranteed. With 32-bit binary IEEE-754, `printf("%.7g", 9.999979e9f);` yields “9.999978e+09”. That is why `FLT_DIG` in C is 6 when IEEE-754 is in use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Naturally, you're correct. I'm amended and have wiki'd this due to the value of your comment.

Comment: Wikipedia is correct. The problem is the decimal print library used in C libm. If you could use a library that prints the minimal number of digits such that the decimal is re-interpreted as the same float, then you would get the expected result. I'm not even sure that the float is not converted to double when serializing with <<...

Answer (score 2):

You will never get a precise number of digits base 10 because the number isn't be stored base 10 and most base 10 fractions have no perfect representation in base 2. There will almost always be a rounding error, and through repeated adding you can magnify that roundoff error.

For example, 1/5 has this binary pattern:

```
111110010011001100110011001101
```

We only care about the last 23 bits (the mantissa) for what you're talking about...

```
10011001100110011001101
```

Notice the repeating pattern of `1001`. To truly represent 0.2 that pattern would have to repeat forever instead of ending with a roundoff of 1.

Multiply that number by enough and the roundoff error is magnified.

If you need to have a precise number of decimal digits, then use integer math and handle the rounding yourself in the case of division in a manner satisfactory to you. Or use a bigint library and rational numbers and end up with huge fractions that take forever to compute, but you'll have infinite precision. Though, of course, any number that can't be represented as a rational like the `sqrt(6)` or `pi` will still have a roundoff error.