# How can I get 9 digits (to left of decimal point) precision for float (wikipedia promises [6-9] digits, but math allows only 7?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

*Double-precision* (IEEE 754): 53-bit significand precision gives **from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits** precision ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Double-precision_examples)).

*Single-precision* (IEEE 754): This gives **from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision.** All integers with 6 or fewer significant decimal digits can be converted to an IEEE 754 floating-point value without loss of precision ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format))

My guess is that by "decimal digits" wikipedia means all 37456 in 37.456

I understand it that lower bound (6 decimal digits for float and 15 for double) is always exact, and sometimes (when?) I can rely even on up to 9 (float) and 17 (double) decimal digits inclusive. *By decimal digits I mean 456 in 37.456*

*But **simple test-snippet shows that even 6th decimal digit lies**:*

```
System.out.println(90f == 90.000_001f); // true. Problem with 6th digit !!!
System.out.println(90f == 90.000_000_000_001f); // true - as expected
System.out.println(90f == 90.000_01f); // false. 5th digit still "exact" - as expected
```

I think 90.000_001 becomes 9.000_000_1 (mantissa in base10) * 10 (E1 exponent)  in internal representation (because 1 digit before decimal point must be used), so only 7th digit becomes inexact, meaning **6 digits is a guarantee (if you convert 90.000_001 to internal representation)**. *But why wiki speaks about [6-9] range?*

Besides, as I understand, maximum possible precision (number of representable decimal digits on the right after decimal point) is defined by simple math as integer part of *log10(2^numberOfBitsForMantissa)*, but **this calculation gives 6 (for float) and 15 (for double)** - I don't include 1 implicit bit (for "integer" part) in numberOfBitsForMantissa (well, I don't know, is it allowed to use this bit with negative exponent like this: 1.11 * E-1 = 0.111). But this +1 bit anyway puts precision limit for float at 7 decimal digits max (unlike [6-9] in wiki).

So **what number of precision digits shall be exact (see my code snippet) and why I see differences between these three:**

1. my code snippet: *up to **6 decimal digits** (inclusive) for float*
2. wiki: ***[6 - 9]*** for float, **[15 - 17]** for double
3. log10(2^numberOfBitsForMantissa) formula, giving ***max 6 (for float)***
   and **max 15** (for double)

> My guess is that **if I convert number** like 99.000_01 **to internal
>   representation** like 9.9_000_01 **then only 6 digits (float) and 15
>   (double) to the left of decimal point (.) are stored in mantissa in this INTERNAL representation** (in 9.9_000_01). **If I
>   have a number x < 1** (for example 0.345_567_8, **then (and only then)** it
>   can be represented as 3.455_678 * E-1 and in this case **7 digits
>   (float) and again 15 digits (double) can be stored** - lg(2^53) and lg(2^52) both have 15 as integer part. Why wikipedia
>   writes different - I have no clue!

My research shows that there is no clear answer to my question: [this (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310276/decimal-precision-of-floats), [this (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130396/why-ieee754-single-precision-float-has-only-7-digit-precision), [this (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629126/analysis-of-float-double-precision-in-32-decimal-digits)

[This (C++) states the following:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138519/arent-6-digits-guarantee-in-single-precision)

for an IEEE754 single precision floating point, the closest number to

```
9999990000
```

is

```
9999989760
```

**What is guaranteed is that your number and the float, when both are rounded to six significant figures, will be the same.**

Comment: The digits of precision counts the total _span_ of non-zero digits regardless of the decimal point's location.  I.e. start counting from the left at the first non-zero digit, through the last non-zero digit. `90.000_001` is 8 digits of precision. You MUST read and fully digest [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Decimal digit means on _both_ sides of the decimal point.  So `90.000_001f` has 8 decimal digits, not 6; which puts it outside of the IEEE 754 accuracy guarantee.

Comment: Having said that, it's not actually clear to me what your question is.

Comment: Why 8 out of guarantee? Single-precision (IEEE 754): This gives from 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @CodeComplete Go read the wiki article again. Going from IEEE 754 to a string and back supports 9 digits.  Going from a string to IEEE 754 and back only supports 6.

Comment: @CodeComplete 6 to 9 means that 6 is guaranteed, and you *may* (in rare circumstances) get 9, while 7 and 8 are more common. Since **8 > 6**, you *don't* have a guarantee on 8.

Comment: @ azurefrog Thank you, I noticed this part. But this is the most confusing part for me - I do not understand why we have difference in "from IEEE 754 to a string and back" vs " from a string to IEEE 754 and back". Sorry for asking...

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123510/whats-the-reason-why-text-float-text-guarantee-6-digit-but-float-text-float) answers some of the question asked here.